# Excel > Find first first/lowest non-zero value in unsorted array

Tags: arrays, excel

Using a complex series of array combinations using standard Excel functions in a single formula (no VBA or UDF's involved), I've got the following result appearing mid-formula. I now need to add one final step to the formula to pull just one number out of this array:

`{0,0,0,4,0,6,7...}`

Using Excel formulas, how can I retrieve the first non-zero figure (in this example, 4) **without any additional references to the array**? Due to the complexity of the calculations it took to produce this array from the source data, I'd rather not do this twice in the same formula.

So I'm looking for functions or operators which can be applied to the array in order to yield the required result - ideally something elegant and simple. `MATCH` and `LOOKUP` fail because they require the array to be sorted. `MIN` fails because the lowest value is 0, not 4.

*NB: The value of each non-zero figure also corresponds with its position in the array (the first would be 1, second would be 2, etc), so the first non-zero number will always be the smallest.*

Comment: may be you could share how you achieved this array. Is it the result of another set of formula?

Comment: @nightcrawler23 - in this example consider a table with 7 rows (much larger in practice). The rest of the formula has been retrieving different columns from the table and comparing them to different measures in order to determine which row it's looking for, so multiplying {0,1,1,1,0,1,1} with {1,0,1,1,1,1,1} and {0,0,0,1,1,1,1} etc, then finally multiplied against an array of the row numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, to determine the indexes of relevant matching rows. Once the cell has its result, all cells to the right are then able to use this index for normal INDEX(MATCH()) functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/{0,0,0,4,0,6,7},1)
```

It finds the maximum of the reciprocals ignoring the error values so the answer is 0.25. Then it takes the reciprocal of that.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't even heard of the `AGGREGATE` function before - I'd actually solved this using `=1/MAX(IFERROR(1/{0,0,0,4,0,6,7}))`, which is pretty much exactly what you've done here but using two functions instead of one. Definitely going to keep `AGGREGATE` on hand going forward...